# Unexpected T_Public on function.

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I am trying to extend a background image control in the Wordpress theme customizer. I have been trying to get this code right and now that I think it should be working I am receiving an unexpected T_Public on this function:

```
public function tab_builtins() {
```

I have attempted to remove the public declaration before it, although that creates a new issue: Unexpected t_function

I have been looking at this code for a long time trying to change minor things but the issue remains. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the full code in question:

```
function WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control_Defaults($wp_customize) {

 /* Substitute the default control for our new one */
    $wp_customize->remove_control( 'background_image' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control_Defaults( $wp_customize ) );

class WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control_Defaults extends WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control {
    public function __construct( $manager ) {

        $this->add_tab( 'builtins', __('Built-ins'), array( $this, 'tab_builtins' ) );


  public function tab_builtins() {

    $backgrounds = array(

            '/wp-content/themes/newtheme/img/backgrounds/background1.jpg', '/wp-content/themes/newtheme/img/backgrounds/background2.jpg', '/wp-content/themes/newtheme/img/backgrounds/background3.jpg', '/wp-content/themes/newtheme/img/backgrounds/background4.jpg', '/wp-content/themes/newtheme/img/backgrounds/background5.jpg'

        );

          if ( empty( $backgrounds ) )
                            return;

                    foreach ( (array) $backgrounds as $background )
                        $this->print_tab_image( esc_url_raw( $background->guid ) );



  }
  }

 }

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'wp_customize_background_image_control_defaults', 11, 1 );
```

Comment: class in a function ..? why you need to do this ?

Comment: Not properly closed method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the closing curly brace right before `public function tab_builtins()`

Put it to close your `__construct` definition properly

Comment: Ahh thank you. I was focusing on the bottom and had a one track mind.